# Parse information from a Hal+JSON object in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I have a spring-data-rest repository producing a hal+json object that I'd like my Angular 2 front end to receive and display.

Hal+Json Object:

```
{
  "_embedded" : {
    "users" : [ {
      "name" : "Bob",
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:4200/api/users/1"
        },
        "user" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:4200/api/users/1"
        }
      }
    }, {
      "name" : "Joe",
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:4200/api/users/2"
        },
        "user" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:4200/api/users/2"
        }
      }
    } ]
  },
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:4200/api/users"
    },
    "profile" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:4200/api/profile/users"
    },
    "search" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:4200/api/users/search"
    }
  },
  "page" : {
    "size" : 20,
    "totalElements" : 2,
    "totalPages" : 1,
    "number" : 0
  }
}
```

I have a service that does a get request to this api.

user.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { User } from './user.model';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'

@Injectable()
export class UserService {

  constructor(private http: Http) {
  }

  findAllUsers(): Observable<Array<User>> {
    return this.http.get('/api/users')
      .map((response: Response) => response.json())
      .map((data: Array<User>) => {
        return data;
      });
  }
}
```

Then my users.component calls the findAllUsers method from the service.

users.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { User } from './user.model';
import { UserService } from './user.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-users',
  providers: [UserService],
  templateUrl: './users.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./users.component.css']
})
export class UsersComponent implements OnInit {
  users: User[];

  constructor(private userService: UserService) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
   this.userService.findAllUsers().subscribe((data: Array<User>) => {
     this.users = data;
   });
  }

}
```

Finally, users.component.html:

```
<h4>Users:</h4>

<div *ngFor="let user of users">
  {{user}}
</div>
```

On my view I get an error stating that: `Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.` I'm not sure how to solve this.

If I try to use the debugger before `data` is returned in the service, then I can see my hal+json object = `data`, and I can see the correct information I want from `data._embedded_users`. But that cannot be mapped to User[] because `_embedded` isn't a property of my user model. Do I need to do something to the Hal+Json object first?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Do I need to do something to the Hal+Json object first?

Is it not obvious? Just extract the data in the service

```
findAllUsers(): Observable<Array<User>> {
  return this.http.get('/api/users')
    .map((response: Response) => response.json())
    .map((data: any) => {
      return data._embedded.users as User[];
    });
}
```

What you had before

```
.map((data: Array<User>) => {
  return data;
});
```

is incorrect, as you made the assumption that the data being passed to the second `map` is the array of users, when actually it's the whole HAL object. Changing it to `any` allows you two extract the users from it.

Comment: Don't you have to remove the `"_links"` from every `user` as well?

Comment: @LambertoBasti You should just print the response data to the console. You can see the whole structure

Comment: I actually had the need to bind the data to a class so in a `.map()` operator e deleted the `_links` field