# Angular - convert HAL to JSON

Tags: json, angular, hal-json

The following service extracts category objects from a REST service which returns them in HAL format. Now I try to convert that response into JSON. For that I searched and tried different solutions, e.g. [chariotsolutions](https://chariotsolutions.com/blog/post/angular-2-spring-boot-jwt-cors_part1/) or [so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43403989/parse-information-from-a-haljson-object-in-angular-2). Some are based on Response from '@angular/http' which is deprecated and which I cannot make work.

How can I do the conversion?

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

import { Category } from './category';

@Injectable()
export class CategoryService {

  private categoriesUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/account/categories';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getCategories(): Observable<Category[]> {
    return this.http.get<Category[]>(this.categoriesUrl);
  }

}
```

The response as HAL

```
{
  "_embedded": {
    "categories": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "hardware",
        "description": "comprises all computer hardware",
        "level": "FIRST",
        "_links": {
          "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/account/categories/1"
          },
          "categoryEntity": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/account/categories/1"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "hardware_notebook",
        "description": "all notebooks",
        "level": "SECOND",
        "_links": {
          "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/account/categories/2"
          },
          "categoryEntity": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/account/categories/2"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/account/categories{?page,size,sort}",
      "templated": true
    },
    "profile": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/account/profile/categories"
    }
  },
  "page": {
    "size": 20,
    "totalElements": 8,
    "totalPages": 1,
    "number": 0
  }
}
```

Comment: The response looks like valid JSON. What is the problem? `Http` is replaced by `HttpClient` https://angular.io/guide/http

Comment: You have NOT an array, just and Object. use map to transform in Array

Comment: @Günther: It is not only JSON but HAL. With the code as shown I get the following error: _Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays._

@Eliseo: I changed `this.http.get<Category[]>(this.categoriesUrl);` to `this.http.get(this.categoriesUrl).map(value => ???;` but do not know how to convert it into an array.

Comment: HAL is just JSON or XML http://stateless.co/hal_specification.html

Comment: That is true. However, when asking the question I thought that the "extra" of HAL needs to be removed so Angular can "use" it. However, as Eliseo points out below it seems that is not necessary anymore with httpClient.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
getCategories(): Observable<Category[]> {
    return this.http.get<Category[]>(this.categoriesUrl)
        .map((result:any)=>{
           console.log(result); //<--it's an object
           //result={"_embedded": {"categories": [..]..}
           return result._embedded.categories; //just return "categories"
        });
}
```

With Rjxs 6.0 we must use pipe(map)

```
getCategories(): Observable<Category[]> {
    return this.http.get<Category[]>(this.categoriesUrl).pipe(
        map((result:any)=>{
           console.log(result); //<--it's an object
           //result={"_embedded": {"categories": [..]..}
           return result._embedded.categories; //just return "categories"
        }));
}
```

Comment: That gives me _ERROR in src/app/category.service.ts(29,21): error TS2304: Cannot find name '_embedded'_ in the compiler. Atom complains as well with the same message: _ReferenceError: _embedded is not defined_

Comment: try this.http.get(this.categoriesUrl).map((result:any)=>{console.log(result)} and check what get return. @Rakesh, if we are using httpClient, we don´t need parse JSON

Comment: Agreed with you on this.

Comment: I tried 
    `getCategories(): Observable<Category[]> {
          return this.http.get(this.categoriesUrl).map((result:any)=>{console‌​.log(result)});
    }`
but that does not compile: _ERROR in src/app/category.service.ts(25,7): error TS2322: Type 'Observable<void>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Category[]>'.
  Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'Category[]'.
src/app/category.service.ts(25,67): error TS2552: Cannot find name 'console‌'. Did you mean 'Console'?_

Comment: sorry, map((result:any)=>{console.log(result);return result;}. But At first you put Observable<any>. I think that you have an OBJECT, not an array. In map you must return the array

Comment: Sorry for the late response. The following code compiles, but it still gives me an _Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays._. The response from the server is: _result from server: [object Object]_. **So how can I convert that object into a Category[]?** Code: 

    `getCategories(): Observable<Category[]> {
      return this.http.get(this.categoriesUrl).map((result: any) => {
        console.log('result from server: ' +  result);
        return result as Category[];
      });
    }`

Comment: Could it be that the response is HAL and not a JSON which can be converted right away into an array (see [1](https://chariotsolutions.com/blog/post/angular-2-spring-boot-jwt-cors_part1/)).

Comment: @Eliseo map() needs to be wrapped in pipe() as of AngularJs 6

Comment: @MonishSen, yes, sometime I forget this detail, I just update the answer (thanks)

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

```
getCategories(): Observable<Category[]> {
    return this.http.get<Category[]>(this.categoriesUrl).map((response)=>{
        return response;
    })
}
```

Comment: That gives me still _Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays._

Comment: Try to debug what value you are getting in response and if it is string then use JSON.parse to get the collection of Categories.

Comment: I tried with the code in my question and got the result posted in the original question.

Comment: @Mfried, the result you posted it's a Object. This Object have as properties: "_embedded","_links", and "page". The property "_embedded" has a property "categories", that is the array you are looking for. It's the reason I suggest you must return result._embedded.categories. Sorry, I put only _embedded.categories. Check the code corrected

Comment: Great! From here I can continue my learning experience. @Rakesh: thanks as well. Here my version: `getCategories(): Observable<Array<Category>> {
    return this.httpClient.get<Array<Category>>(this.categoriesUrl).map((result: any) => {
      return result._embedded.categories;
    });
  }`